# Alea GPU how to get Licensemanager.exe

Tags: c#-4.0, aleagpu

I am working on some GPU calculation algo using Alea GPU for the first time. I am unable to find *licensemanager.exe* file to install the license. I have signed up for community account and have the license code. I was unable to find *licensmanager.exe* and hence getting compiler error. Attached is image for your reference.

[image: Sample test]

Can anybody please advice what I am doing wrong?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        [AOTCompile]
        static void SquareKernel(deviceptr<double> outputs, deviceptr<double> inputs, int n)
        {
            var start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
            var stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
            for (var i = start; i < n; i += stride)
            {
                outputs[i] = inputs[i] * inputs[i];
            }
        }
        static double[] SquareGPU(double[] inputs)
        {
            var worker = Worker.Default;
            using (var dInputs = worker.Malloc(inputs))
            using (var dOutputs = worker.Malloc<double>(inputs.Length))
            {
                const int blockSize = 256;
                var numSm = worker.Device.Attributes.MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT;
                var gridSize = Math.Min(16 * numSm, Common.divup(inputs.Length, blockSize));
                var lp = new LaunchParam(gridSize, blockSize);
                worker.Launch(SquareKernel, lp, dOutputs.Ptr, dInputs.Ptr, inputs.Length);
                return dOutputs.Gather();
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var inputs = Enumerable.Range(0, 101).Select(i => -5.0 + i * 0.1).ToArray();
                var outputs = SquareGPU(inputs);
                Debug.Print("inputs = {0}", String.Join(", ", inputs));
                Debug.Print("outputs = {0}", String.Join(", ", outputs));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks right, but if you don't have license installed, it will fail. The license manager executable you can find in the nuget package's tool folder.

Comment: can you please guide me actually i have tried installing package 
Install-Package Alea.CUDA in my project  as mentioned on the developer site but still could not find licensemanager.exe file.

Comment: the package will be extract to a folder named packages under your solution folder, where you can find the executable. Please reference [here](http://quantalea.com/static/app/manual/compilation-installation.html) and [here](http://quantalea.com/static/app/manual/compilation-license_manager.html). Note it is not under your PATH, you must start command line tool in that folder.

Comment: Thankyou Very much finaly found it.